# How to generate a Doodle like poll id on app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to generate an id for a poll that can be used in links. The id should not be not to easy to guess. Is there a preferred way to generate such an id on google app engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UUID - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID

```
String key = UUID.createNewUUID().toString();
```

As close to unique as makes no odds, and impossible to 'guess'.

Comment: java.util.UUID does not have createNewUUID. I'm using UUID.randomUUID().toString(), looks great. Do you recommend something else than the jdk implementation?

Comment: No sorry, didn't have the API to hand so that was from memory :)